# Proving set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove two sets are equal, and I am wondering if my method of proof is ok.

I know the "standard" way to show two sets are equal is to show that each is a subset of the other.  Doing this in one direction is easy, but in the other direction, I can see it will be difficult (doable, but not easy).

On the other hand, I can show that each subset has the same size very easily by building an easy bijection between them.  Is this enough to show they have the same size?  It makes intuitive sense, but I want to make sure it is good.  That is, I want to know if,

$(A\subseteq B) \wedge (|A| = |B|) \implies A = B.$

Thanks!

Comment: "And", not "or". Two countably finite sets are equivalent if one is the subset of another, *and* they have the same size. $(A\subseteq B) \mathbf \land (|A|=|B|) \iff A=B$.  But only if they are finite.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: is that true? I don't think it is true for infinite sets. Consider $2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, for instance. There is an obvious bijection between them, but $2\mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AWertheim, Graham was correcting the question: the OP uses "$\vee$" instead of "$\wedge$". The answer to the question is of course no.

Comment: Yes, I did mean and, sorry.  And thank you for the answers!

Comment: @user28111 Do not use the incorrect tag. The difference is there for a reason. This is [tag:elementary-set-theory]. The other tag is for questions of a more technical nature, not just any question involving sets.

Answer (score 1):

No: $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$, $\vert\mathbb{Z}\vert=\vert\mathbb{Q}\vert$, but $\mathbb{Z}\not=\mathbb{Q}$.

(Advanced aside: sets for which your argument would work are called "Dedekind-finite;" assuming the axiom of choice, all Dedekind-finite sets are really finite, but in ZF it is consistent that there are infinite Dedekind-finite sets.)

Answer (score 1):

If your sets are finite,  yes.  If they are infinite, then no.   Counterexample for infinite:   The even natural numbers are a subset of the natural numbers,  they have the same cardinality, but they are not equal